# Automatic addition using R

Tags: r

I have this matrix:

```
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    8   36  180
[2,]    5   24   21   32
[3,]    9   40    6   48
[4,]   13   56   45  180
[5,]   17   72  117   28
```

and this vector:

```
> x
[1] 10 25 34 41 59
```

I should SUM the elements of the row and then subtract the result with the respective value on the x vector.

Example:

```
10 - (1 + 8 + 36 + 180)
25 - (5 + 24 + 21 + 32)
34 - (9 + 40 + 6 + 48)
41 - (13 + 56 + 45 + 180)
59 - (17 + 72 + 117 + 28)
```

How can I create a vector with the results of those computations?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
x-rowSums(y)
```

Comment: daroczig, is it possible to sum the intermediate values? I mean... a <- 10 - (1 + 8 + 36 + 180) a <- a + 25 - (5 + 24 + 21 + 32) etc etc ?

Comment: @Dail: you mean `sum(x-rowSums(y))`?

Comment: Do you mean something like `t(x - apply(y,1,cumsum))` ??